# PHP mail() Gmail - how to format text display?

Tags: php, email, encoding, gmail, hotmail

Im working on a system the to make bookings for a recoding studio. At the moment I am working on sending email to notify the owner a booking has been made and send an overview to the person who made the booking.

The script I have works but the layout is messed up in Gmail. I'm thinking it might be the encoding.

I'm using str_pad() to add all the full stops add all and make the values align

This is What is Should look like

```
Recording Time..........................| 8 Hours
Editing and Production time.............| 4 Hours 
Discs...................................| 1
Setup and Rehearsal time................| 1 Hour
```

But it end up looking more like this in gmail. Although there are the same number of full stops used.

```
Recording Time.......................| 8 Hours
Editing and Production time.............| 4 Hours 
Discs...........................| 1
Setup and Rehearsal time...............| 1 Hour
```

This is what it actually looks like. http://dl.dropbox.com/u/11163035/stack_PHP_Gmail.png

Also It displays correctly if you view the original message in Gmail.

Comment: This is an issue of font type gmail is using. Its not monospaced. With a text email you have no control over that.

Comment: is it just simple text. try HTML formating

Answer (score 1):

It's not because of encoding. It's happening because of the reason mention by @datasage above in your question's comment.

You can use html `<pre></pre>` tags. It forces text to be displayed in a fixed-width font (usually Courier), and it preserves both spaces and line breaks.

or, you can send email in text formats!

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, I Was tying to avoid using html formatting but guess it'll be easier.

Comment: Instead of HTML formattings you can use CSS. However I think the problem remains the same. So just provide a text only email (normally dispayed with a fixed-width font which should work for your dots) and (by using a multipart message) a HTML part.